# Binary Search in C using recursion

Tags: c, recursion, binary-search

The program crashes in finding a number which is not available in the array.The code works perfectly when i search for elements which are available in the array.Help much appreciated.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int binarySearch(int a[],int s,int key)
{
    int middle;

    if(s!=1)
        middle=s/2;

    if(a[middle]==key)
        return 1;

    else if(key<a[middle])
        binarySearch(a,middle,key);

    else if(key>a[middle])
        binarySearch(&a[middle],middle,key);

    else
        return 0;
}

void main()
{
    int i;
    int a[]={1,2,3,4,6,9,10,11};

    for (i =0;i<8;i++)
        printf("%i ",a[i]);

    if(binarySearch(a,8,5))
        printf("\nFound");
    else
        printf("\nNot Found");
}
```

Comment: Try changing the base case to ```if(s<=1) return 0;```

Comment: `void main()` is undefined behaviour. if `s` is equal to `1` you are using `middle` uninitialized.

Comment: There is `bsearch()` function in `stdlib.h`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
if(s!=1)
    middle=s/2;
if(a[middle]==key)
    return 1;
else if(key<a[middle])binarySearch(a,middle,key);
else if(key>a[middle])binarySearch(&a[middle],middle,key);
```

to

```
if (s != 1){
    middle = s / 2;
    if (a[middle] == key)
        return 1;
    else if (key<a[middle])binarySearch(a, middle, key);
    else if (key>a[middle])binarySearch(&a[middle], middle, key);
}
```

The variable `middle` is initialized only if `s!=1`.

I have run this code and got the value `Not Found` for input `5`.

If you are running your code in release mode, try building it in debug mode and run step by step you will see what happens when middle is used directly without assigning it a specific value. This is harmful.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

The code `if(key<a[middle])binarySearch(a,middle,key);` does not return anything.

Try `if(key<a[middle]) return binarySearch(a,middle,key);`

This may still not work as you intend it to, but at least you will get past the major, immediately visible, cause of runaway recursion.

Answer (score 0):

Because there is no case if the s == 1. "Middle" is not initialized and a[middle] is potential crash, or it will just go infinite.

Answer (score 0):

A few notes:

Every branch of a recursive function should return something. You'll need to modify your recursive calls to return the call

Change

```
binarySearch(a, middle, key)
```

to

```
return binarySearch(a, middle, key)
```

Also, make sure middle is computed properly. You don't properly initialize it in the situation where s == 1. You'll want this to start at 0 most likely.